# unable to load photos in Django after deploying to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have made a portfolio + blog website using Django. it works perfectly when running it locally but after I deployed it to Heroku, accessing the portfolio redirected me to a 500 server error. I turned on debug mode and when I did the same, it didn't throw a 500 server error, however, the pictures won't load. this is very confusing and help will be very appreciated...

settings.py

```
    from pathlib import Path
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'projects',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'personal_portofolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["personal_portofolio/templates/"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'personal_portofolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)

import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'personal_portofolio.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = WhiteNoise(application)
```

what my project directory looks like:

```
C:.
├───blog
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───personal_portofolio
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───projects
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───static
│   │   └───img
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
└───staticfiles
    └───admin
        ├───css
        │   └───vendor
        │       └───select2
        ├───fonts
        ├───img
        │   └───gis
        └───js
            ├───admin
            └───vendor
                ├───jquery
                ├───select2
                │   └───i18n
                └───xregexp
```

Edit: after setting DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS to True, I am getting this error in the Heroku logs `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'staticfiles/project1.png'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **settings.py** seems fine, try adding this code to project-name/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) # add static file URL to django urlpatterns
```

If your trying to host media files **note that Heroku does not support media hosting you might need to connect your Django application with something like amazon s3 bucket**. You can find an article about it [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html).